# Require Sample code for Loopback User Roles

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am new to Loopback framework of node js.
I am trying to understand the concept of **User Roles** that loopback provides for the **User** model. I have been referring the below link for understanding the concept.

[Defining and using roles](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles)

So, can anyone provide me a sample code from which i can understand this concept programatically as there is not much information provided in the above link and i am not able to understand the concept properly.

If anybody has come across any Github public repository containing any sample code for the same will also do.

Can anybody please help me with this.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you expect the code to do? There's already code in the link, what's wrong with that? What's missing?

Comment: I require a sample code on github from where i can easily understand the concept of creating user roles and user role management in loopback.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific example for user roles, but the concepts are demonstrated in a few examples:

- https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-faq-user-management
- https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control

See all examples maintained by StrongLoop at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example

Comment: The sencond link that you have provided contains the code that creates some users and assigns statically to them. But i would like to do it using the apis of Role, RoleMapping, etc. models.

Comment: See this example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/loopbackjs/dynamic$20roles/loopbackjs/71Zz3aWHuu4/92ViMfRemkoJ